# How to have a text nova field readonly and with a default value fetched from DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have this Laravel nova code where there is a readonly field. But this field should be populated with a value that already exists on a database table.

Do you know how to use Eloquent inside the Text nova field to get that database value?

```
    new Panel('Settings', [
                    ...JSON::make('Settings', [
                        Text::make('Site Locale', 'siteLocale')->readonly(),
                    ])->data
                ]),
```

Comment: Should have resources tied to the fields right? Like a model?

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly, there are some nova fields for relationships and things like that. But in this case is not with relationships is just to get a value from the db table associated with this Nova resource. Thanks

Comment: So.. Settings is a table? Can you show the table?